# SSIS - Converting 4 digit string to time value

Tags: sql, ssis, expression, data-warehouse

I'm trying to replicate the following T-SQL statement which does what I want with an expression:

TIMEVAL is a 4 digit int representing hh:mm

```
DATEADD(hour,(TIMEVAL/ 100) % 100, 
DATEADD(minute,(TIMEVAL/1) % 100, CAST('00:00' as time(2)))) as TimeOpened
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why not just put this script in the SSIS process flow as a execute SQL Task?

Answer (score 1):

Derived Column Code:

```
(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4)(time),1,2) + ":" 
+ SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4)(time),3,4))
```

Example
Data
1.

[image]

2.Derived Column

[image]

3.View

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t as int = 1250;
SELECT TimeOpened = 
    Right ('0' + Convert (varchar, @t/100), 2) 
    + ':' 
    + Right ('0' + Convert (varchar, @t - ( @t/100) * 100), 2)
```

In expression:
   LEFT((DT_STR,4,1250)(T),2) + ":" + RIGHT((DT_STR,4,1250)(T),2)

Note: This will give erroneous result if T (the time in integer) has only 3 digits. But your question says time is 4-digit integer.